# Getting Auth error while connecting Jenkins job to Puppet master server

Tags: jenkins

I just create a new Jenkins job and updated Exec command also added SSH server name .

Before this I have added an entry of Puppet master server IP in Global config in Jenkins portal .

Then I have generated ssk keys on Jenkins server , i got Public and Private keys so I've added public key under Puppet master server under  **~/.ssh/authorized_keys ** by using VIM . Then I've added Private key in Jenkins credentials .

Later I ran Jenkins job it got falied because it is not able to establish connection between jnkins job and Puppet master server . Then I have myown user id at puppet master by using that I updated details in jenkins credentials like z0125964@puppet2  and given userid and password but it is also failed.

Please suggest where did I done mistake.

[Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RC6y1.png)